# Set Consisting of Harmonics of Integer Powers of 2?

Tags: number-theory, harmonic-functions, harmonic-numbers

If one defines "harmonics" as natural number fractions of a number, is there a name for the set consisting of all harmonics of all integer powers of two?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational

Comment: Thanks, so would the answer would be "Inverse Dyadic Rationals" or is there another accepted term for (2^b)/a with b drawn from integers and a from natural numbers?

Comment: Every positive rational number can be written as a sum of terms of the form $\frac{2^b}{a}$, since every positive natural number can be written as a sum of distinct powers of $2$.

Comment: @Jack: I don't think the OP wants to take sums.

Comment: @James: I've never seen anyone need a name for this particular subset of the rationals. The dyadic rationals have the pleasant property of being closed under both addition and multiplication, whereas these guys are only closed under multiplication.